# Переключатель языка JS

Tags: javascript, смена-языка

У меня супертупой вопрос: пытаюсь сделать переключатель языка на JS. Существует некоторое количество блоков, внутри тексты. Для каждой фразы есть свой перевод в объекте **LanguageDataArr**. И я хочу чтобы при изменение языка в **select** изменялся язык всей страницы (пока не обращаем внимания на title, hash etc.)
Чтобы реализовать это дал всем элементам специальный класс "lng-" но при обращении таким образом получается либо null (querySelector) либо пустая коллекция(getElementsByClassName), хотя на видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKx31x5u_SQ у него это срабатывает. Подскажите что не так делаю?

```js
const LanguageDataArr = {
  "one" : {
    "en" : "one",
    "ru" : "один",
  },
  "two" : {
    "en" : "two",
    "ru" : "два",
  },
  "three" : {
    "en" : "three",
    "ru" : "три",
  },
};


const langSwitcher = document.getElementById("langSwitcher");
langSwitcher.addEventListener("change", changeLanguage);


function changeLanguage() {
  let currentLang = langSwitcher.value;


  for (let key in LanguageDataArr){
    document.querySelector("lng-" + key).innerHTML = LanguageDataArr[key][currentLang];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <p class="textOne lng-one">one</p>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <p class="textTwo lng-two">two</p>
</div>
<div class="block3">
  <p class="textThree lng-three">three</p>
</div>
<select name="langSwitcher" id="langSwitcher">
  <option value="en">en</option>
  <option value="ru">ru</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".lng-" + key)` - перед lng точку добавить забыли

Comment: Менял туда сюда разные методы и забыл. С точкой значение показывает null

Comment: И вот интересно что используя getElementsByClassName в глобальной области видимости и пытаясь взять lng- возвращается пустая HTML коллекция

Comment: Покажите куда вы точку добавляете... Я пример добавлял. И если её добавить к коду в вопросе - всё работает

Comment: вот так: document.querySelector(".lng-" + key).innerHTML = LanguageDataArr[key][currentLang];

Comment: Сейчас стало работать c методом querySelector.  Спасибо за подсказку! А почему не получается также сделать с getElementsByClassName?

Comment: Потому что [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) возвращает коллекцию, а querySelector во-вращает эл-т.. `document.getElementsByClassName(".lng-" + key)[0].innerHTML` так будет работать, но нет смысла это использовать в данном случае

Comment: @InDevX `document.getElementsByClassName(".lng-" + key)[0].innerHTML` - вот так не будет работать

Comment: Всем спасибо. Я кажется понял. У меня работает все в малеьком проекте,  созданном для примера но не работает в оригинальном. Может ли быть такое что функция LanguageDataArr не работает изза похожих классов типа такого: class = "lng-service nav__text" и существующих других элементов с классами "service" или "services"?

Comment: @Grundy да, без точки, скопировал и забыл изменить

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема в неверном селекторе. Для поиска по классу в функцию [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) нужно передавать строку начинающуюся с точки.

```js
const LanguageDataArr = {
  "one": {
    "en": "one",
    "ru": "один",
  },
  "two": {
    "en": "two",
    "ru": "два",
  },
  "three": {
    "en": "three",
    "ru": "три",
  },
};


const langSwitcher = document.getElementById("langSwitcher");
langSwitcher.addEventListener("change", changeLanguage);


function changeLanguage() {
  let currentLang = langSwitcher.value;


  for (let key in LanguageDataArr) {
    document.querySelector(".lng-" + key).innerHTML = LanguageDataArr[key][currentLang];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <p class="textOne lng-one">one</p>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <p class="textTwo lng-two">two</p>
</div>
<div class="block3">
  <p class="textThree lng-three">three</p>
</div>
<select name="langSwitcher" id="langSwitcher">
  <option value="en">en</option>
  <option value="ru">ru</option>
</select>
```

Для использования [.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getelementsbyclassname) лучше хранить ключ локализации в отдельном атрибуте. В этом случае можно будет идти по всем элементам нуждающимся в локализации и обновлять значения.

Стоит обратить внимание, что в [.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getelementsbyclassname) имя класса передается **без** точки.

```js
const LanguageDataArr = {
  "one": {
    "en": "one",
    "ru": "один",
  },
  "two": {
    "en": "two",
    "ru": "два",
  },
  "three": {
    "en": "three",
    "ru": "три",
  },
};


const langSwitcher = document.getElementById("langSwitcher");
langSwitcher.addEventListener("change", changeLanguage);
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");

function changeLanguage() {
  let currentLang = langSwitcher.value;

  
  for (let el of elements) {
    el.innerHTML = LanguageDataArr[el.dataset.key][currentLang];
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <p class="textOne lng" data-key="one">one</p>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <p class="textTwo lng" data-key="two">two</p>
</div>
<div class="block3">
  <p class="textThree lng" data-key="three">three</p>
</div>
<select name="langSwitcher" id="langSwitcher">
  <option value="en">en</option>
  <option value="ru">ru</option>
</select>
```